# IPostbackeventhandler returning no results for an automated table

Tags: asp.net

I got this code which extends the tablerow to make them clickable.

```
namespace ClickableTableRow
{
    public class ClickableTableRow : TableRow, IPostBackEventHandler
    {

        public ClickableTableRow()
            : base()
        { }

        private EventHandler _click;
        public event EventHandler Click
        {
            add { _click += value; }
            remove { _click -= value; }
        }

        protected virtual void FireClickEvent()
        {
            if (_click != null)
                _click(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, 
                Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, String.Empty));
            base.RenderAttributes(writer);

        }

        public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
            FireClickEvent();
        }
   }
```

The code above works well if I create the table manually, but when i create the table in the code behind it seems to be firing postbacks but no resuts returned. is there any thing wrong i might doing. my codebehind looks like:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    } 

    protected void row1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Messagebox.Text = "message";
    }

     ClickableTableRow.ClickableTableRow row1;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        Table Table1 = new Table();

        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();

        row1= new ClickableTableRow.ClickableTableRow();
        row1.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='hand'");

        cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Text = "llllll";
        row1.Cells.Add(cell1);
        Table1.Rows.Add(row1);

        row1.Click += new EventHandler(row1_Click);
        this.pnl2.Controls.Add(Table1);
       }
}
```

Comment: Or move base.OnLoad(e) at the end of the method and give an ID to Table1

Comment: @Adrian Iftode: thanks for your solution. I made changes to include the ID. but now I cannt set the tr IDs as they get created by a slq query, also tried a for loop with no good outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this code to Init or PreInit.  This is the typical part in the lifecycle where dynamic controls should be added.